# why the electricity has been called the AC power?

Tags: electricity

the electricity look like not changing the electric current way between the hot wire and the gnd wire.So it is should be the DC power?

Comment: dialect what?looking at the below answer.Then stopped complain without any help.i wrote this for someone who understand and can helping.if you can't,don't make the server's memory to be more extravagant.

Comment: If you can't write passable English, get someone to write it for you or don't post here.  Badly broken English, like what you wrote in the question and this last comment, is quite annoying to those that do speak English.  It will only result in downvotes and votes to close questions as *unclear*.

Comment: whatever.However,just pretty weird that you have been annoyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AC means alternating current. The ground wire is like the word indicates connected to ground. The potential on the hot wire alternates in a sinus wave between high and low. In other words between positive and negative in respect to the ground

Comment: so that model said the hot wire must transmit the sinus pulse of electric.But the alternation is the change of electric current way between two poles-positive and negative,then they would be over the diode to be a DC pulse power?